# Add CSS class to a flagged node

Tags: 7, theming, flags

I want to add CSS classes to flagged nodes in order to theme them.

Found the documentation [How to add CSS classes to nodes, based on flags set](https://www.drupal.org/node/312220), but this solution is for D6.

Can someone help me to figure out how to make it work with D7?

Comment: Have you tried that code in your own `yourtemplate_preprocess_node()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in your template.php of your theme. Change MYTHEME to the name of your theme and bookmark to the machine name of your flag. And change node-flag-bookmark to the css class you want to be added to your node.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $flag = flag_get_flag('bookmark'); // Machine name of your flag.
  if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($variables['node']->nid)) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'node-flag-bookmark';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Class are added when you refresh the page. It is possible to add class without a page refresh?